# Qt Webkit : Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2008, qt4, qtwebkit

**Greeting**

When i try to load picture from local drive i get the following error !!!

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///c:/qt/4.8.5/examples/webkit/imageanalyzer/resources/images/mtRainier.jpg
```

This is how i try to load image in HTML.

```
<img id="ImageObject" src="file:///c:/qt/4.8.5/examples/webkit/imageanalyzer/resources/images/mtRainier.jpg" alt="" width="304" height="228">
```

How can i fix this ?

Im using `QT 4.8.5` , `Qt Webkit` And `Visual Studio 2008`.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem !!! `JPEG` was not supported in my qt. The error is totally irrelevant. Add `JPEG` support to your project and you're good!

PS: If you have same problem and you want to know this solution will help you or not, Try following code and see supported formats, If `JPEG` is not among them, Then you have same problem otherwise this solution wont work for you!

```
qDebug() << QImageWriter::supportedImageFormats();
```